# face-api and tensorflow.js not working in browser

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js, face-api

I'm trying to run this example in the browser

https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/index.html#getting-started-browser

Specifically this code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="assets/face-api.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/commons.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/faceDetectionControls.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar"></div>
  <div class="center-content page-container">

    <div class="progress" id="loader">
      <div class="indeterminate"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative" class="margin">
      <video onloadedmetadata="onPlay(this)" id="inputVideo" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
      <canvas id="overlay" />
    </div>

    <div class="row side-by-side">

      <!-- face_detector_selection_control -->
      <div id="face_detector_selection_control" class="row input-field" style="margin-right: 20px;">
        <select id="selectFaceDetector">
          <option value="ssd_mobilenetv1">SSD Mobilenet V1</option>
          <option value="tiny_face_detector">Tiny Face Detector</option>
        </select>
        <label>Select Face Detector</label>
      </div>
      <!-- face_detector_selection_control -->

      <!-- check boxes -->
      <div class="row" style="width: 220px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hideBoundingBoxesCheckbox" onchange="onChangeHideBoundingBoxes(event)" />
        <label for="hideBoundingBoxesCheckbox">Hide Bounding Boxes</label>
      </div>
      <!-- check boxes -->

      <!-- fps_meter -->
      <div id="fps_meter" class="row side-by-side">
        <div>
          <label for="time">Time:</label>
          <input disabled value="-" id="time" type="text" class="bold">
          <label for="fps">Estimated Fps:</label>
          <input disabled value="-" id="fps" type="text" class="bold">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- fps_meter -->

    </div>


    <!-- ssd_mobilenetv1_controls -->
    <span id="ssd_mobilenetv1_controls">
      <div class="row side-by-side">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="minConfidence">Min Confidence:</label>
          <input disabled value="0.5" id="minConfidence" type="text" class="bold">
        </div>
        <button
          class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
          onclick="onDecreaseMinConfidence()"
        >
          <i class="material-icons left">-</i>
        </button>
        <button
          class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
          onclick="onIncreaseMinConfidence()"
        >
          <i class="material-icons left">+</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </span>
    <!-- ssd_mobilenetv1_controls -->

    <!-- tiny_face_detector_controls -->
    <span id="tiny_face_detector_controls">
      <div class="row side-by-side">
        <div class="row input-field" style="margin-right: 20px;">
          <select id="inputSize">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Input Size:</option>
            <option value="128">128 x 128</option>
            <option value="160">160 x 160</option>
            <option value="224">224 x 224</option>
            <option value="320">320 x 320</option>
            <option value="416">416 x 416</option>
            <option value="512">512 x 512</option>
            <option value="608">608 x 608</option>
          </select>
          <label>Input Size</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="scoreThreshold">Score Threshold:</label>
          <input disabled value="0.5" id="scoreThreshold" type="text" class="bold">
        </div>
        <button
          class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
          onclick="onDecreaseScoreThreshold()"
        >
          <i class="material-icons left">-</i>
        </button>
        <button
          class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
          onclick="onIncreaseScoreThreshold()"
        >
          <i class="material-icons left">+</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </span>
    <!-- tiny_face_detector_controls -->

  </body>

  <script>
    let forwardTimes = []
    let withBoxes = true

    function onChangeHideBoundingBoxes(e) {
      withBoxes = !$(e.target).prop('checked')
    }

    function updateTimeStats(timeInMs) {
      forwardTimes = [timeInMs].concat(forwardTimes).slice(0, 30)
      const avgTimeInMs = forwardTimes.reduce((total, t) => total + t) / forwardTimes.length
      $('#time').val(`${Math.round(avgTimeInMs)} ms`)
      $('#fps').val(`${faceapi.utils.round(1000 / avgTimeInMs)}`)
    }

    async function onPlay() {
      const videoEl = $('#inputVideo').get(0)

      if(videoEl.paused || videoEl.ended || !isFaceDetectionModelLoaded())
        return setTimeout(() => onPlay())


      const options = getFaceDetectorOptions()

      const ts = Date.now()

      const result = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(videoEl, options).withFaceExpressions()

      updateTimeStats(Date.now() - ts)

      if (result) {
        const canvas = $('#overlay').get(0)
        const dims = faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, videoEl, true)

        const resizedResult = faceapi.resizeResults(result, dims)
        const minConfidence = 0.05
        if (withBoxes) {
          faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedResult)
        }
        faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedResult, minConfidence)
      }

      setTimeout(() => onPlay())
    }

    async function run() {
      // load face detection and face expression recognition models
      await changeFaceDetector(TINY_FACE_DETECTOR)
      await faceapi.loadFaceExpressionModel('/')
      changeInputSize(224)

      // try to access users webcam and stream the images
      // to the video element
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: {} })
      const videoEl = $('#inputVideo').get(0)
      videoEl.srcObject = stream
    }

    function updateResults() {}

    $(document).ready(function() {
      renderNavBar('#navbar', 'webcam_face_expression_recognition')
      initFaceDetectionControls()
      run()
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this is not working ( I have loaded the associated libraries into assets, i.e., https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/tree/master/dist and moving the other files from this example here

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/tree/master/examples/examples-browser

What am i doing wrong? I am loading this on a page on my site here

https://moodmap.app/webcamFaceExpressionRecognition.html in case you want to see what's happening in the browser.

#### Based on changes below,

Here is the node server where I am setting where things are held - is it possible to just change this instead? As it is coming up with a separate issue with the shard needed in the model as well now when making the changes suggested below.

Thanks!

```
const config = require('../../config');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { wsEngine: 'ws' });
const mysql = require('mysql');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const ExpressMysqlSessionStore = require('express-mysql-session')(expressSession);
const sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils');

// remove from header "X-Powered-By: Express"
app.disable('x-powered-by');

server.listen(config.serverParams.port, config.serverParams.address, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`);
});

/* DATABASE */
global.db = mysql.createConnection(config.db);
db.connect();
/* DATABASE */

/* SESSION */
const sessionStore = new ExpressMysqlSessionStore(config.sessionStore, db);
const session = expressSession({
    ...config.session,
    store: sessionStore,
});
app.use(session);
/* SESSION */

app.use(express.static(config.frontendDir));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './src/assets')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './src/assets/weights')))

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    //can reaplce * with website we want to allow access
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
  });

app.get([
    '/signup',
    '/stats',
    '/pay',
], (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(`${config.frontendDir}${req.path}.html`)));

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave: true
}));

io.on('connection', socket => {

    socket.use((packet, next) => {
        if (packet[0]) {
            console.log('METHOD:', packet[0]);
            const sessionData = socket.handshake.session.user;
            const noSessionNeed = [ 'login', 'signup', 'checkAuth' ].includes(packet[0]);
            let error;
            if ( ! sessionData && ! noSessionNeed) error = { code: -1, message: 'You need to login in extension!' };
            if (error) return next(new Error(JSON.stringify(error)));
            else next();
        }
    });

    const auth = require('./auth')(socket);
    socket.on('checkAuth', auth.checkAuth);
    socket.on('login', auth.login);
    socket.on('signup', auth.signup);
    socket.on('logout', auth.logout);

    const users = require('./users')(socket);
    socket.on('users.get', users.get);

    const sentiment = require('./sentiment')(socket);
    socket.on('sentiment.get', sentiment.get);
    socket.on('sentiment.set', sentiment.set);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {

    });

});
```

Reason being still getting an error for some reason as below,?

```
fetchOrThrow.ts:11 Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to fetch: (404) , from url: https://moodmap.app/assets/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json
    at fetchOrThrow.ts:11
    at step (drawContour.ts:28)
    at Object.next (drawContour.ts:28)
    at fulfilled (drawContour.ts:28)
(anonymous) @   fetchOrThrow.ts:11
step    @   drawContour.ts:28
(anonymous) @   drawContour.ts:28
fulfilled   @   drawContour.ts:28
async function (async)      
run @   webcamFaceExpressionRecognition.html:142
(anonymous) @   webcamFaceExpressionRecognition.html:158
j   @   jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
I   @   jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I am checking your application at https://moodmap.app/webcamFaceExpressionRecognition.html, I am getting error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to fetch: (404) , from url: https://moodmap.app/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json`  Are you taking about this?

Comment: Yes - Where does this link into the rest of the javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the error you were talking about in the question is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to fetch: (404) , from URL: 
https://moodmap.app/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json
```

So, this error implies that the file `tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json` could not be found. And this is happening for all other manifest.json files as well, as I see in your website.

You mentioned in the question that all your associated libraries are into **assets** folder. So, your `tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json` file and other manifest.json files also in `assets` folder and I am giving you the solution according to that but if you change location of files to another folder, just replace `assets` with that whatever folder where your file is in.

**face-api.js Line:1976**
[image: face-api.js Linke: 188-190]

Here, in **line 1976** you see `defaultModelName`. This tells about the file to load.

---

**1.** So if your app has only the issue with loading `tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json` [ **For this case, It is showing 404 error for all manifest.json so jump below**] then

**face-api.js Line: 5627**
[image: face-api.js Line: 470]

Go to line 5627 in face-api.js and change
`"tiny_face_detector_model"` with
`"./assets/tiny_face_detector_model"`

---

**2.** If all your manifest files are showing 404 error while loading, which true for this case because all your files are in assets folder.

So, in that case go to **line number 1976 of face-api.js**,

just replace:

```
var defaultManifestFilename=defaultModelName+"-weights_manifest.json";
```

with:

```
var defaultManifestFilename="./assets/"+defaultModelName+"-weights_manifest.json";
```

That means just **concatenate the folder name** or **path** where the manifest file exists to the mentioned variable. And this will fix the path issue for all **manifest.json** files in your application.

**NOTE:** If there is a problem finding the code with line number I mentioned then use search.

Comment: When doing this, I now am getting a separate error to do with the shards associated with the models - i'll check the code as above.

Comment: When you get a chance made some changes above, i think there is still some issues with how the shards with the models are being routed, unsure why though!

Comment: where is your `tiny_face_detector_model-shard1` file?

Comment: same folder Manish

Comment: The last line of `tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json` contains `paths:["tiny_face_detector_model-shard1"]}]` . Just change the path to `paths:["./assets/tiny_face_detector_model-shard1"]}]` . Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: So that I will add it to the answer as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220720/discussion-between-manish-and-michael-holborn).